# I would like to have a query to pull separate row for year year in the time range and reorganize that data as per my requirement

Tags: sql, date, for-loop, range, row

This is my Input table:

```
create table ##Ratings
( Symbol varchar(20), Ratingvalue varchar(20), Ratingdate DATE ); 

insert into ##Ratings values ('12GN0','MM','2013-07-09'),
('69358','CA','2021-04-19'),('69358','NR','2015-06-13'),
('69358','CB','2009-09-07'), ('32079','FS','2016-09-19'),
('32079','MM','2013-04-02') 

select * from ##Ratings
```

**Desired output is:**

```
        2024    2023    2022    2021    2020    2019    2018    2017    2016    2015    2014    2013    2012    2011    2010    2009
12GN0   Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     No      No      No      No
69358   Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     NR      NR      NR      NR      NR      NR      Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes
32079   Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     Yes     No      No      No      No
```

If there is a rating for a period from 2009 to 2024, it should be Yes.
Otherwise, it should be No.
If there is "NR", it should be "NR".

Comment: Your desired output and your question is conflicting. Why does 12GNO have a 'Yes' from 2013 to 2024 when it only have a rating in 2013. Do you mean if it has a rating in one year, then all the subsequent year should have a 'Yes'? If that is the case, how will 'NR' work itself into that logic?